# Eclipse Subclipse shows in the bottom of eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, subclipse

I create some views in eclipse and after that my Subclipse plugin on action Synchronize with repository shows just panel at the bottom of eclipse (not clickabel or dragable). I tried to reset perespective but it doesn't help.

I try to oper view from Windows view the same result[panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3A0ir.png). Is it posiible to return this plugin on working state?

Comment: It is the status bar. When the synchronization view was active it shows incoming outgoing changes on status bar. It is non editable. What problem you are facing exactly?

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK Eclipse doesn't open view in front of Team Synchronizing perespective

Comment: Not clear. Add screen shot and edit your post.